# [Html][CSS]Padding is not the same for my navigation menu elements

Tags: html, css, width, padding

As you can see in the picture, the padding for each element from my list (navigation menu) differs but I have used the same padding for all of them...

I know that the problem is that the `padding`/`width` is modifying the content and I don't know how to fix it!

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: You should post your code instead of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same padding. See [padding documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp). If you want full width you should try `width: 100%` or `display: block` (`a` elements have `display: inline` as default, as pointed in other answer).

[image]

Comment: Feel free to mark one of the answers as a solution to help people to find it the future (and to regard the user with rep points) ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding `display: block` to your `nav a` selector because `a` selector is not a block level element by default. Try adding this to your code.

```
nav a {
display: block;
}
```